# method "setImage:" not find on GPUImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, gpuimage

I'll set an image on a GPUImageView.

```
UIImage *adjustedImage = [lookupFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:0];
[self->_imgView setImage:adjustedImage];
```

But in the `GPUImageView` Class is not the `setImage:` method.
Can someone post the whole method of `setImage:` or tell me how I can find this method?
I thought I can copy the method from the `UIImageView.m` file and paste it in the `GPUImageView.m` file. But I can't find the `UIImageView.m` file.

**GPUImageView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GPUImageContext.h"

typedef enum {
    kGPUImageFillModeStretch,                       // Stretch to fill the full view, which may distort the image outside of its normal aspect ratio
    kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio,           // Maintains the aspect ratio of the source image, adding bars of the specified background color
    kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill     // Maintains the aspect ratio of the source image, zooming in on its center to fill the view
} GPUImageFillModeType; 

/**
 UIView subclass to use as an endpoint for displaying GPUImage outputs
 */
@interface GPUImageView : UIView <GPUImageInput>
{
    GPUImageRotationMode inputRotation;
}

/** The fill mode dictates how images are fit in the view, with the default being kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio
 */
@property(readwrite, nonatomic) GPUImageFillModeType fillMode;

/** This calculates the current display size, in pixels, taking into account Retina scaling factors
 */
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CGSize sizeInPixels;

@property(nonatomic) BOOL enabled;

/** Handling fill mode

 @param redComponent Red component for background color
 @param greenComponent Green component for background color
 @param blueComponent Blue component for background color
 @param alphaComponent Alpha component for background color
 */
- (void)setBackgroundColorRed:(GLfloat)redComponent green:(GLfloat)greenComponent blue:(GLfloat)blueComponent alpha:(GLfloat)alphaComponent;

- (void)setCurrentlyReceivingMonochromeInput:(BOOL)newValue;

@end
```

Comment: `GPUImageView` is not a standard class.  Please post a link to provide more information about it.

Comment: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: I didn't notice a `GPUImageView` in that repo; if I've missed it then please post a link to the header/implementation, if there isn't then I don't understand your question.

Comment: I posted the header file in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPUImageView is not a subclass of UIImageView. It has no `-setImage:` method. You don't set UIImages to it. It doesn't work that way.

A GPUImageView is a destination for your filter chain. To display an image within it, you set the GPUImageView as a target either of your GPUImagePicture instance or of the filters that follow from that (if you want to display the filtered output). You do not set a UIImage as the contents of that view. Again, it's not a UIImageView.

There are plenty of examples for how to use a GPUImageView with the samples that ship with GPUImage. I also explain how this works in my documentation for the project. Please review that before proceeding further.

Comment: Ok. Now I change the class from UIView to GPUImageView. But if I'll run my app it crashes. Xcode says: 2014-05-27 21:25:36.181 CameraApp[6112:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView sizeInPixels]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109d19930' and here -[UIView  it says that it is an UIView. But why? I changed it to GPUImageView.

Comment: @DeviJP you must have forgot to change the type in outlet.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code for GPUIamge i hope this helpful

```
GPUImageView *gpImageView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
GPUImagePicture * inputImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
[inputImage processImage];
[inputImage addTarget: gpImageView];
[self.view addSubview:gpImageView];
```